# PhP - How to listen to a form button

Tags: php

I want to listen to this button called submitDetails which is my Register button. Basically I want to send the information from the form over to mysql but that part should be ok for now I would like my button to listen to calls. And when called, it should gather all the information which I think I've done in my lines of code but I'm not sure If I've done that part correctly or not (I've used isset($_GET..) instead of $_POST ?? Thought I'd need to GET them before POSTing .. or am I wrong?

I'm havn't played with PhP that much and I havn't made a button previously to listen to calls and then act so I'm not sure.. another way I read is ajax but its pretty much confusing I couldn't get my head around it, it can only work by sending you to another php page right? Or can I make it so it sends data to mysql in the current PhP page?

Here is the lines of code please show me how my button could listen to calls and then put

```
   // here you do whatever you want when button is pressed
```

Okay here is code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(http://i45.tinypic.com/2iw61x5.png);
background-color: #333;
}
</style>
<?php

    echo "<form><font color='white'><P ALIGN='right'>• Hello guest, please <a href='loginPage.php'><font color='white'>login</font></a> / <a href='registerPage.php'><font color='white'>register</font></a>.</P></font>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";  // starting from here
    echo "<tr><td>

            <u><P ALIGN='left'><b><font size='5' color='black'>Register_______________________________________________________________</font></b></P></u>   
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</form></table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b><Username: </b></TD>
            <TD><input type='text' name='Username' id='Username' size='121.5' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b>Password: <b></TD></P>
            <TD><input type='password' name='Password' id='Password' size='122' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b>Re-Password: <b></TD></P>
            <TD><input type='password' name='Re-Password' id='Re-Password' size='118' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b>Email: <b></TD></P>
            <TD><input type='password' name='EmailAddress' id='EmailAddress' size='126' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<form method='post'><divstyle='float:center'><P ALIGN='center'><input type='submit' id='submitDetails' name='submitDetails' value='Register'></P></div></form>";

    $username = isset($_GET['Username']);
    $password = isset($_GET['Password']);
    $repassword = isset($_GET['Re-Password']);
    $email = isset($_GET['EmailAddress']);

    if(!$email == "" && (!strstr($email,"@") || !strstr($email,".")))
    {
        echo "<h2>Please enter valid e-mail.</h2>\n";
        die ("Thank you.");
    }

    if(empty($username)  || empty($password) || empty($repassword) || empty($email))
    {
        echo "<h2>Please fill in all fields, click the back button to retry</h2>\n";
        die ("Thank you.");
    }

    $message = "Hello $username" .", We have successfuly recieved all your details and stored in our database, please proceed by logging in the website if havn't already.";
    $subject = "Media Registration";

    mail("hidden",$subject,$message,$email);



    ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is hard to understand what kind of a help you need. :|

Comment: You don't get and post the data.
$_GET and $_POST are two methods of request methods, it depends on the form on which you should use.

Comment: I just want my button to listen to for users to click it and then I want to send the form data over to mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(http://i45.tinypic.com/2iw61x5.png);
background-color: #333;
}
</style>
<?php

    echo "<form method='post' action='?'><font color='white'><P ALIGN='right'>• Hello guest, please <a href='loginPage.php'><font color='white'>login</font></a> / <a href='registerPage.php'><font color='white'>register</font></a>.</P></font>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";  // starting from here
    echo "<tr><td>

            <u><P ALIGN='left'><b><font size='5' color='black'>Register_______________________________________________________________</font></b></P></u>   
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b><Username: </b></TD>
            <TD><input type='text' name='Username' id='Username' size='121.5' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b>Password: <b></TD></P>
            <TD><input type='password' name='Password' id='Password' size='122' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b>Re-Password: <b></TD></P>
            <TD><input type='password' name='Re-Password' id='Re-Password' size='118' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table width='850' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center' bgcolor='#ECF7F7'>";
    echo "<tr><td>
            <TR>
            <TD><b>Email: <b></TD></P>
            <TD><input type='password' name='EmailAddress' id='EmailAddress' size='126' /></TD>
            </TR>
            </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<div style='float:center'><P ALIGN='center'><input type='submit' id='submitDetails' name='submitDetails' value='Register'></P></div></form>";

if(isset($_POST['submitDetails']))
{
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $repassword = $_POST['Re-Password'];
    $email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];

    if(!$email == "" && (!strstr($email,"@") || !strstr($email,".")))
    {
        echo "<h2>Please enter valid e-mail.</h2>\n";
        die ("Thank you.");
    }

    if(empty($username)  || empty($password) || empty($repassword) || empty($email))
    {
        echo "<h2>Please fill in all fields, click the back button to retry</h2>\n";
        die ("Thank you.");
    }

    $message = "Hello $username" .", We have successfuly recieved all your details and stored in our database, please proceed by logging in the website if havn't already.";
    $subject = "Media Registration";

    mail("zdamagedz@hotmail.co.uk",$subject,$message,$email);

}

    ?>
```

I fixed the form tags, I added method="post" and the action="?" in order to post the data to the same page, in the "POST" method.

I have also added the `isset($_POST['submitDetails'])` condition, in order to check whether the submit button was clicked or not.

Comment: so if(isset($_POST['submitDetails'])) means when the button is clicked yes? And if so then I just need to do the mysql thing inside that if statement then..

Comment: Yes, That's true, of course you have to set the form's method as post and not get, otherwise you should use `$_GET['submitDetails']`.

Comment: okay man thanks alot i was about to use ajax and send my form input data over to another php page when the button is clicked which seems like a lot longer and perhaps harder way for me to do.. thanks again :D)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your  tag you need to specify the location, where the request and all the form that will be sent. it must be a php file, which can receive this data either from $_GET or $_POST arrays, read them and do whatever you need. use this form tag:  create a file called formPost.php in the same location of your current file, open it and write:  that might give you a sight where you are now